# IronPython and Targetting to MS Framework 1.1

Tags: ironpython, .net-1.1

In IronPython Studio -> Properties -> General Tab i see a Property with Name Target Plataform and found Microsoft Framework 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0, selected 1.1 and next opened my Visual Studio 2003 -> Add Reference and for my surprise this not work. Not compatibility. Why? What i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IronPython since version 1.0 is only compatible with .NET 2.0 and higher, it uses Generic and features only available since .NET 2.0.